# Gatsby gives an error "Error: Type with name "File" does not exists" during build at the moment of graphql fetching

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Trying to build a gatsby website but I get a hard to debug error related to the graphql schema (i think). 
The error I get is this:

```
success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.004 s
success load plugins — 0.276 s
success onPreInit — 0.004 s
success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.018 s
success initialize cache — 0.008 s
success copy gatsby files — 0.009 s
success onPreBootstrap — 0.005 s
Starting to fetch data from Prismic
Fetch Prismic data: 919.580ms
success source and transform nodes — 0.975 s
error Type with name "File" does not exists


  Error: Type with name "File" does not exists

  - TypeStorage.js:44 SchemaComposer.get
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeStorage.js:44:13

  - TypeMapper.js:86 TypeMapper.get
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeMapper.js:86:44

  - TypeMapper.js:608 TypeMapper.typeFromAST
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeMapper.js:608:17

  - TypeMapper.js:105 TypeMapper.getWrapped
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeMapper.js:105:17

  - TypeMapper.js:272 TypeMapper.convertOutputFieldConfig
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/TypeMapper.js:272:114

  - configAsThunk.js:19 resolveOutputConfigAsThunk
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/utils/configAsThunk.js:19:41

  - configAsThunk.js:37 Object.keys.forEach.name
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/utils/configAsThunk.js:37:22

  - Array.forEach

  - configAsThunk.js:36 resolveOutputConfigMapAsThunk
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/utils/configAsThunk.js:36:27

  - ObjectTypeComposer.js:147 GraphQLObjectType.gqType._fields
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/ObjectTypeComposer.js:147:114

  - Array.reduce

  - SchemaComposer.js:130 SchemaComposer.buildSchema
    [operaloki]/[graphql-compose]/lib/SchemaComposer.js:130:12

  - schema.js:500 
    [operaloki]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/schema.js:500:47
```

I don't know what this type `File` is and I couldn't find any occurences of this word in my files.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Might have to do with the content in your Prismic CMS. Tough to debug without more info or a repository.

Comment: @RobertCooper, I don't know what I should provide because this error happened after I changed name to the parent directory of the project.

Comment: It could be in your `gatsby-node.js` file then. If the code in `gatsby-node.js` is looking at the wrong directory to construct some of your files, then it will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

In a recent update of the `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql` plugin, the owner pushed the support of `gatsby-image`.
Since then, he updated the sample that you should get start with but for existing project, You'll need to add these three plugins to make sure everything works as expected:

- `gatsby-source-filesystem`
- `gatsby-transformer-sharp`
- `gatsby-plugin-sharp`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I added gatsby-source-filesystem and that helped.
However, it is not clear to me why Prismic all the sudden started to require it. Earlier with the same models, it was not required.